# How to use SCALAR to read line-by-line after reading in a large file (Perl) ?

Tags: perl, text-files, readfile, scalar

I am reading a file into a `SCALAR` by using:

```
open FILE, "<", $filename or error_out("Error opening $filename");
read FILE, my $buffer, -s $filename;    
close FILE;
```

I am not sure how to think of the "new" `$buffer`/`SCALAR` type. Is it a string? An array? How to go through it line-by-line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, I recommend you use the following to read the file:

```
my $buffer = do {
    open(my $fh, '<', $filename)
        or error_out("Error opening $filename: $!");
    local $/;
    <$fh>
};
```

Note the removal of the useless and potentially incorrect `-s`. Note the use of a lexical variable for the file handle rather than a global one. Note the inclusion of the underlying error message in the error message.

---

1. The variable is a scalar. The value is a string.
2. ```
   for my $line (split(/^/m, $buffer)) {
       ...
   }
   ```

   But why not just read it a line at a time.

   ```
   open(my $fh, '<', $filename)
       or error_out("Error opening $filename: $!");

   while (my $line = <$fh>) {
       ...
   }
   ```

Answer (score 3):

```
for my $line (split(/\n/, $buffer)
{
    # do whatever with $line
}
```

Or if you're not specifically attached to reading the whole file into memory all at once:

```
open(FILE, "<", $filename) or error_out("Error opening $filename");

while (<FILE>)
{
    # do whatever with $_
}

close(FILE);
```

Comment: `split(/\n/, $buffer)` will remove trailing blank lines, but that might not be a bad thing.

Answer (score 2):

It is unusual to see `read` used in a Perl program. Most often `readline FILE` (or the equivalent `<FILE>`) is more appropriate.

If you don't need the entire file in memory at once then you can iterate over the lines using

```
while (my $line = <FILE>) {
  # Process $line
}
```

or if you would rather have the whole file in an array of lines then you can do

```
my @lines = <FILE>;
```

The regular method of reading a whole file into a single string is to undefine `$/` - the input file separator - like this

```
local $/;
my $contents = <FILE>;
```

but that is generally much less useful than the first two options.