# How to go to a specific line in a multi-line string variable (Perl)?

Tags: perl, text-files, line, scalar

I am reading a text file into a `SCALAR` variable by using

```
open FILE, "<", $filename or print("Error opening $filename");
read FILE, my $buffer, -s $filename;    
close FILE;
```

Later on I am counting the number of lines in that `SCALAR` variable. How can I go to a specific line within that `SCALAR` variable without iterating through it?

Comment: Unless you have fixed-width lines, there's no way to know where line X begins without iterating through it *somehow*. But this seems like an [XY problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341); perhaps you should explain exactly what you're trying to achieve. Are you trying to replace bits of text in a file? Searching for matching lines? Deleting all lines after the nth? Something completely different?

Comment: Also, you seem to have completely ignored [ikegami's advice](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22155225/176646) on how you can improve this code.

Comment: Find the line  before last, match strings, and count total lines - all for further analysis down the code...

Comment: You can do all of those by iterating through the file line-by-line, no need to read the entire contents into a scalar. Perhaps what you really wanted to ask in this question was, "How can I get the second-to-last line from a file?"

Comment: I also need the # of lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the question you originally posed is that unless you're dealing with a fixed-width file, you can't skip to a certain line without iterating *somehow*.

However, based on your comments, it seems that there's no need to read your entire file into a scalar in the first place. You can get both the second-to-last line and a total line count by simply iterating through the file like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my ($count, @previous);
while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;

    $count++;

    push @previous, $_;
    shift @previous if @previous > 2;
}

say "Count: $count";
say "Second-to-last line: $previous[0]";

__DATA__
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu
fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

#### Output:

```
Count: 6
Second-to-last line: fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
```

For simplicity, I used the special `__DATA__` block instead of an external file. To read a file as above, do:

```
open my $fh, '<', '/path/to/file' or die "Failed to open file: $!";

while (<$fh>) {
    ...
}

close $fh;
```

Why is this better than reading the whole file into a scalar? If your file is large, reading the whole thing into memory all at once can be costly. Unless you have a good reason not to, it's generally better to read files one line at a time and process them as you go.